# Locally path connected definition question

Tags: algebraic-topology

> A space $X$ is locally path connected if, for each $x \in X$ and every
>   open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is an open $V$ with $x \in V \subseteq U$ such that any
>   two points in $V$ can be joined by a path in $U$.

For the last part, does this mean that, if $f : I \rightarrow X$ is the path that maps $a$ to $b$ in $V$, $f(I) \subseteq U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition in Hatcher says that $X$ is locally path connected if, for each $x \in X$ and every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is an open set $V$ with $x \in V \subseteq U$ such that $V$ is path connected. (So for any two points $a,b \in V$, there exists a continuous path $f : I \to X$ with $f(0) = a$ and $f(1) = b$ such that $f(I) \subseteq V$.)

Having said that, for the purposes of proving the lifting theorem (pages 61-62 of Hatcher), it is enough to assume only that any two points $a, b \in V$ can be joined by a continuous path $f : I \to X$ with $f(0) = a$, $f(1) = b$ such that $f(I) \subseteq U$. This is not the definition of "locally path connected" (at least if you read Hatcher) - it is just the condition required by the proof of that particular theorem. Perhaps different books use different definitions!

Comment: This is the definition given on page $28$ of J.J. Rotman's Introduction to Algebraic Topology.  But is my interpretation of the wording correct?  As in "a path in a space" means the image of the path is a subset of the space?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct interpretation!

Comment: And as I said, either definition is fine for the purposes of proving the lifting theorem!